# Convergence to $1$ or $-1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I’m looking for a recurrent sequence $x_0, x_1,\dots, x_n$ that converges to $1$ if $x_0$ is positive and to $-1$ if $x_0$ is negative. The recurrent relation should be something that can be approximated by a polynomial.

Is there such a sequence in mathematics?

P.S. I’m sorry for the lack of formality.

Comment: $x_n=\frac {x_{n-1}}{|x_{n-1}|}$ ?

Comment: +1; That's what I call minimalistic.

Comment: I’m looking for something that can be approximated by a polynomial. I edited the question

Comment: It is not really clear what you mean by "something that can be approximated by a polynomial". If you have a recursion $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ and replace $f$ by an approximating polynomial (you did not clarify in what sense you mean "approximating"), then the recursion might behave quite differently. So, your question needs some clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible without restrictions. Indeed, the recurrence that you want must be contracting as it eventually maps any positive to $1$, while a polynomial does the opposite.

You can achieve the desired property with the simple non-polynomial recurrence

$$x_{n+1}=\sqrt[3]{x_n}.$$

---

For a quasi-linear solution,

$$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+\text{sgn}(x_n)}2.$$

But this is of little interest, as

$$x_{n+1}=\text{sgn}(x_n)$$ is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Although the term *can be approximated by a polynomial* is not rigorous, here's something you may like:
$$
x_{n+1} = x_{n} + (x_{n} - x_{n}^{3}) e^{-x_{n}^{2}}
$$
which satisfies the limit condition (by the proof with my intuition and python experiment) and the function $f(x) = x + (x - x^{3})e^{-x^{2}}$ *can be approximated* by $p(x) = x$ when $|x|$ is large.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A possible function for your recursion could be

$$f(x) = \frac 4{\pi}\arctan x$$

The interesting fixpoints here are $x=1$ and $x=-1$.

$f$ can be approximated by its Taylor polynomials but it is unclear what you expect if you replace $f$ by an approximating polynomial. The recursion might not have the same fixpoints and might not converge the way you would like to have it.

Back to $f(x) = \frac 4{\pi}\arctan x$:

Since $f$ is an odd function, you only need to check convergence of $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ to $1$ for $x_0>0$.

For $x_0>1$ you have $1< x_n < 2$ and $f$ is contracting on $[1,2]$, hence the recursion converges to the fixpoint $x=1$.

For $0<x_0<1$ you have $0<x_n <1$ and additionally $f(x)>x$ (which you may check for yourself). Hence, $x_n$ is increasing and bounded from above, hence it converges as well to the fixpoint $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The rational function

$$f(x)={2x\over x^2+1}$$

should do the job. It has fixed points at $x=0$, $1$, and $-1$. It's easy to verify that if $x\gt1$ then $0\lt f(x)\lt1$, and if $0\lt x\lt 1$ then $x\lt f(x)\lt1$, so for any $x_0\gt0$, the sequence defined by $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ will converge to $1$. By symmetry (since $f$ is an odd function), any $x_0\lt0$ will give a sequence converging to $-1$.